# IE 10 & 11 make fixed backgrounds jump when scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, background, fixed

When you scroll with the mouse wheel in Windows 8 the fixed background image bounces around like crazy. This only affects IE 10 and IE 11. This affects elements with `position:fixed` as well. 
Here is an example with a fixed background-image:

http://www.catcubed.com/test/bg-img-fixed.html

Here is example code:

```
#section{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#eee;
    background-position: top left;
    background-image: url("images/7.png");
    background-size: auto; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Is there a solution to keep the background still in IE 10 and 11?

Comment: Found this: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795070/mouse-wheel-issue-with-position-fixed-images

Comment: Fixed elements inside fixed elements cause the jumping problem. Change the position of parent element to be, for example absolute. Absolute mostly works without any other change, or change according to your needs.

Comment: For me, the jumpy behavior was caused by ``opacity:0.99`` on the HTML element (a fix for bolder fonts on Mac).

Comment: Unfortunately this question is closed. I also struggled with this issues, during investigation I found this Javascript-based workaround:
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) { // if IE
        $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
            // remove default behavior
            event.preventDefault(); 

            //scroll without smoothing
            var wheelDelta = event.wheelDelta;
            var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
            window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollPosition - wheelDelta);
        });
}

Comment: I just came across a case where I was able to reduce the stuttering by removing `box-shadow` from elements that overlap the fixed background.

Comment: Why is this question closed as off-topic? It's clearly about code issue and It seem to be unresolved. For me the only thing that hellped was wrapping the fixed ellement and set to the wrapper: 
 #fixwrapper{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform : translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
 }

Answer (score 49):

I know it is a bit late for an answer but I've had the same problem and was able to fix it by adding these attributes to my css file

```
html{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;    
}
body{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**From the comments:**

> This solution stops scroll events from firing on the window, so do be careful if you're using anything that relies on such events firing. [codepen.io/anon/pen/VawZEV?editors=1111](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VawZEV?editors=1111) ( overflow: hidden, scroll events don't work) [codepen.io/anon/pen/PNoYXY?editors=1111](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNoYXY?editors=1111) ( overflow: auto, scroll events fire) - Dan Abrey

So this might cause some problems in your projects. But I don't see another way to workaround this bug in IE.

Comment: This solution stops scroll events from firing on the window, so do be careful if you're using anything that relies on such events firing.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VawZEV?editors=1111 
(<html> overflow: hidden, scroll events don't work)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNoYXY?editors=1111 
(<html> overflow: auto, scroll events fire)

Comment: This solution is not desireable for mobile browsers, because it redefines the default scroll container which leads to slower scroll and other issues (e.g. query panel won't hide on scroll).

Comment: I ended up adding this only when the browser is IE for desktop, so that the scroll containers in other browsers can work normally. For me it was ok that some features may not work in IE. .... I really don't understand how a company like MS is not able to remove this bug, which is now known for 2 years ...

Comment: This is the only solution I found that worked too, but I'm having an odd bug with it where I cannot scroll down the page when my mouse is over the fixed navigation bar at the top. Removing html { overflow: hidden } stops this from happening, but also breaks the parallax fix. I'm guessing this may be what @DanAbrey was referring to. Any ideas on how this solution can work without stopping these scroll events?

Answer (score 25):

**This looks like a z-index bug, try adding z-index: 1.**

Looking into this, I've found the best way to debug is to:

Create a simple element at the top of the page, e.g.

```
 <style>#test {position: fixed; background: red; top: 0; left: 0; width: 4em}</style>
 <div id="test">Test</div>
```

In all the above cases, this works correctly, and the scroll is smooth. So this proves it can be done! Now slowly add your properties back in, until you are able to get the element with position fixed to work in the context of your site.

I then found that adding a z-index to the fixed items resolved the issue. (e.g. z-index: 1)

I also discovered that once a position is set on a child element, the bug presents it's self from that point down/onwards.

> **So you need to ensure none of the child elements have a position set,**
>   **or if they do, you explicitly set a position on each child.**

E.g.

```
<!-- Works -->
<div style="position: fixed;">
    <div>Nice</div>
    <div>Wicked</div>
    <div>Cool</div>
</div>

<!-- Element with position: relative, experiences the bug -->
<div style="position: fixed;">
    <div style="position: relative;">sad</div>
    <div>sad</div>
    <div style="position: fixed;">happy</div>
</div>
```

It's fixable, but will require some tweaking!

Comment: I had a similar issue with a bootstrap fixed navbar at the top of the screen. If the page also contained some fixed or absolute text, the navbar would wobble when scrolling. Just adding z-index = 1 to the fixed/absolute text fixed it.

Comment: I've tried all the above and can't get it to work. Still jumps only on mouse scroll :(

Comment: To add to this, Make sure you don't have a position:fixed element as a child of a position:fixed element make it positioned absolutely instead It will still be fixed as the parent is fixed

Comment: "you explicitly set a position on each child" Worked for me.

Comment: **z-index** did it for me, thank you! (IE11, Windows 10)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a workaround (tested on Windows 8.1):

**Move the "background" CSS property to the BODY element**. Currently it is on the DIV element with id="filler". Here is the resulting CSS:

```
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        background: #fff url(blue-kitty.jpg) no-repeat fixed center 100px;
    }

    #filler {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .big-margin {
        margin-top: 500px;
    }
```

Comment: Wow... can't believe people overlooked this... this is actually the only semi-viable fix to the issue, until MS fixes IE's smooth scrolling. Yes, it will work for a single background image, but it's all we've got at the moment, and can be done in two minutes.

Comment: And won't work if you have multiple items on the page that are fixed.

Comment: This worked for me. Tried all the solutions within this answer and finally moving the background image to the body tag worked. I have two items on my page that are fixed, namely the background image and back to top button

Answer (score 4):

try to turn off smooth scrolling option.

Internet Options - Advenced Tab - Use Smooth Scrolling

it's like rendering bug.... MS IE team is investigating....

Comment: @JPHellemons this only work for you. Smooth Scrolling is enabled by default. You users will have that problem.

Answer (score 3):

just simply define body container to relative.

```
<style>
    body
    {
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The fix in my case was to simply remove the z-index property from the element that has  position:fixed, IE then stopped the strange flickering.

(disabling smooth scrolling on IE options worked while having he z-index property but that's not a solution since users would most likely have it on by default).