# Issue in IE 11 : Fixed background move up-down with scroll

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position, internet-explorer-11

I have a fixed header on top of my webpage. It's looking good in chrome and any other browser except internet explorer.

But when i tried to run web-page in IE 11, top header jerk up and down with scroll.

This bug also posted on **[Internet Explorer Feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/821953/ie10-ie11-fixed-background-images-move-when-touched-scrolled)**

**For me this bug only seen, when page has horizontal scroll bar.**

My CSS style for fixed top header:

```
.dashboard-fixed-top
 {
    background-color: #3b5999;         
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible;        
    padding-top: 5px;
    height:32px; 
    max-height:32px; 
}
```

[Code in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26JTq/4/) **[In Fiddle It's working perfectly]**

I did't get any appropriate solution to overcome of this problem.

Would it be possible to fix this problem?

Any help would be appreciated, bunch of Thanks in advance...!!!

Following two screen-shots described my problem....

[image: In this screen-shot my blue fixed header showing correctly]

[image: After moving window scroll a bit lower my blue header look like this (i.e. move up and hide some part of header inside browser command bar)]

Comment: provide your raw code.

Comment: are you using a doctype?

Comment: Yes, '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377810/ie-10-11-make-fixed-backgrounds-jump-when-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your doc type to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I'm having very similar situation, and this is  not a solution for my problem.