# Element in Internet Explorer jumps while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Everything is working smoothly on Chrome, but on IE 9 the green element is jumping on scroll, why?

[Here is a JSFiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/Token/d9w8zm23/)

```
body{
    height:1000px;
}

.block{
    width:50px;
    height:20px;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a limitation in IE. I used code to perform the same effect which was smooth in chrome, but in IE jumpped.

Comment: [Check the answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377810/windows-8-makes-fixed-backgrounds-jump-when-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel). Smooth scrolling when disabled does make a bit of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's occurring in chrome too if you move scrollbar faster.

Please consider using `fixed` position instead of setting css `top` everytime scroll event is occurred because when scroll event is occurred,The scroll's already moved and a page get rerendered according to new scroll position.what you are doing is to change how it looks right after the page get rerendered.

in addition, scroll event/resize event would potentially be called dozens of times per second.So those kind of code easily causes a performance issue.

Comment: I really need to use relative position, but i understand the only solution here is position fixed ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the jQuery Waypoints plugin http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: I dont think waypoints can help me, I need sticky element with position relative